# Add dynamic height for iframe in angular

Tags: angularjs, iframe

Is there any way we can track the changes inside and iframe? I want to track a change inside an iframe and set the new height accordingly.

I am new to angular world need some one to guide me . I have the following code

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="iframe_wrap">
    <iframe id="displayframe" src="file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/test2.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:2px solid black;width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: {{count}}px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = document.getElementById('displayframe').contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
}]);
```

Is there any listener to track change inside an iframe available?

Edit: My above example works on document ready i.e I am able to get the height on ready of document. My question is what if later a div a new div is inserted after a click inside an iframe. I want the iframe to have a dynamic height without having a scroll bar.

Comment: what exactly you mean ? Like if there is div of dynamic height in iframe, change in that also change Height of iframe  ?

Comment: What if a new div is added in inside my iframe after document is ready then how do we change the height. My iframe consist of comment section where customer can post a comment. I don't want a scroll bar but I want the height of iframe to adjust dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#displayframe" ).on('load', function() { 
     var divElement = $(this).contents().find("div");
     var height     = divElement.height();
     $scope.count = height;
  });
});
}]);
```

If you have div inside , You can change your iFrame height using this. You can modify as per your need . Hope this will help you .:)

Comment: What if a new div is added after document is ready then how do we change the height. My iframe consist of comment section where customer can post a comment. I don't want a scroll bar but I want the height of iframe to adjust dynamically.